# Update Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I got the crash after I'm upgrade my xamarin.forms to 2.3.4.247 version. it's my first time to upgrade my xamarin.forms. I don't know about the crash. Can someone help? Thanks

[image]

Comment: It seems like, Something wrong in LoginScreen Xaml file. Can you please share your login screen xaml file?

Comment: I saw your [question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/100541/system-argumentexception-has-been-thrown-an-item-with-the-same-key-already-been-added), since `System.ArgumentException has been thrown an item with the same key already been added` not play again, what's your new problem?

Comment: about "System.ArgumentException has been thrown an item with the same key already been added" it's already done but just running in my device IOS then in device Android it's not working. How about that?can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<custom:MasterPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="DutchWallet.LoadingScreen" xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:DutchWallet;assembly=DutchWallet" xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:DutchWallet.Localization;assembly=DutchWallet">
    <custom:MasterPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" Source="Images/background" Aspect="AspectFill" />
            <Label x:Name="WelcomeToLabel" Text="{i18n:Translate LoadingScreen_WelcomeTo}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0.18, 1, .1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontFamily="Open Sans" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" FontSize="42" />
            <Label Text="{i18n:Translate LoadingScreen_DucthWallet}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0.28, 1, .1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontFamily="Open Sans" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" FontSize="42" />
            <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.50, 0.55, .5, .5" Source="Icons/logo" Aspect="AspectFit">
                <Image.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Rectangle" iOS="0.50, 0.55, .5, .5" Android="0.50, 0.55, .4, .5" />
                </Image.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds>
            </Image>
            <Label x:Name="VersionLabel" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0.75, 1, .1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontFamily="Open Sans" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" Text="Version x.x" FontSize="14" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </custom:MasterPage.Content>
</custom:MasterPage>
```

Maybe this xaml what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning your solution, then re-build it? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I was tried it.. it's running in IOS device but in Android device still crash.